# Is there a generic implementation for NavigableMap subMap/headMap/tailMap?

Tags: java, collections, guava

I've implemented `NavigableMap` a few times, but it always seems like a bit more work than it should be. While it's a very large interface, things like `java.util.AbstractMap` and Guava's `ForwardingNavigableMap` provide much of the boilerplate. However, neither seems to help with the core implementation of `subMap`/`headMap`/`tailMap` (i.e. aside from the overloading for specifying inclusivity flags). For instance, it seems like `firstEntry` of a sub/tail map could just call `ceilingEntry(minKey)` or `higherEntry(minKey)`, depending on whether `minKey` is inclusive. Does Guava or something else provide an easy way to implement these generically? Alternatively, is there a reason I'm overlooking that such an implementation is not practical?

Comment: Just a question... What is the problem with the JDK's `NavigableMap` implementations which prompted you to implement this interface?

Comment: There doesn't need to be a problem with them. :-) In this case, I'm implementing a client for a web service that exposes paginated resource lists. The client will expose those resources in a `NavigableMap` that fetches pages of resources as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Guava doesn't currently expose `AbstractNavigableMap`, but I'm not sure even that would help you significantly.  TBH, I don't see where it'd buy you much: `firstEntry` can always be defined as `Iterables.getFirst(entrySet().iterator(), null)`, whether you're a complete map or a submap or whatever.  Guava could *conceivably* provide a complete implementation of `subMap` and friends that iterated via `higherEntry` each time, but that's rarely what you want, compared to a more efficient handwritten iterator implementation.

Comment: `AbstractNavigableMap` might not help much as-is, but I think it could be extended to provide some useful support here. For my REST client example, the server implements get-by-key, delete-by-key, first-page,  last-page, page-after, and page-before, which is all you really need for a functional `NavigableMap`. When you're fetching contents from a server (as opposed to a local data structure), I don't think you can be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible to implement what I'm looking for, but there doesn't seem to be an existing framework for it. Particularly, I want the `NavigableMap` interface implemented in terms of `get` and `remove` for an arbitrary key and navigation in terms of `first`, `last`, `next`, `previous`. I'm guessing that part of the reason is that I'm representing an external service interaction rather than an internal data structure. The use case is less common and the performance expectations are different.

The following code is my draft implementation. It's only somewhat tested and is intended as a proof of concept. It uses Guava's `Iterators`, `Ordering`, and `ForwardingNavigableMap`, along with nullness annotations from the Checker Framework.

```
/**
 * Abstract base implementation of {@link NavigableMap} that provides all but
 * the following methods:
 * 
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link Map#containsKey(Object)}</li>
 * <li>{@link Map#get(Object)}</li>
 * <li>{@link Map#remove(Object)}</li>
 * <li>{@link SortedMap#comparator()}</li>
 * <li>{@link NavigableMap#lowerEntry(Object)}</li>
 * <li>{@link NavigableMap#floorEntry(Object)}</li>
 * <li>{@link NavigableMap#ceilingEntry(Object)}</li>
 * <li>{@link NavigableMap#higherEntry(Object)}</li>
 * <li>{@link NavigableMap#firstEntry()}</li>
 * <li>{@link NavigableMap#lastEntry()}</li>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * Note that {@link Collection#size()} is implemented in terms of iteration
 * using {@code firstEntry} and {@code higherEntry}, and therefore executes in
 * time proportional to the map size. Subclasses may wish to provide a more
 * efficient implementation.
 * 
 * @param <K> the type of keys maintained by this map
 * @param <V> the type of mapped values
 */
public abstract class AbstractNavigableMap<K, V> extends AbstractMap<K, V> implements
        NavigableMap<K, V> {

    @Override
    public abstract boolean containsKey(Object key);

    @Override
    public abstract V get(Object key);

    @Override
    public abstract V remove(Object key);

    @Override
    public K firstKey() {
        return firstEntry().getKey();
    }

    @Override
    public K lastKey() {
        return lastEntry().getKey();
    }

    @Override
    public K lowerKey(K key) {
        return lowerEntry(key).getKey();
    }

    @Override
    public K floorKey(K key) {
        return floorEntry(key).getKey();
    }

    @Override
    public K ceilingKey(K key) {
        return ceilingEntry(key).getKey();
    }

    @Override
    public K higherKey(K key) {
        return higherEntry(key).getKey();
    }

    @Override
    public Map.Entry<K, V> pollFirstEntry() {
        final Map.Entry<K, V> e = firstEntry();
        if (e != null) {
            remove(e.getKey());
        }
        return e;
    }

    @Override
    public Map.Entry<K, V> pollLastEntry() {
        final Map.Entry<K, V> e = lastEntry();
        if (e != null) {
            remove(e.getKey());
        }
        return e;
    }

    @Override
    public NavigableMap<K, V> descendingMap() {
        return new ForwardingNavigableMap<K, V>() {
            @Override
            protected NavigableMap<K, V> delegate() {
                return AbstractNavigableMap.this;
            }

            @Override
            public NavigableMap<K, V> descendingMap() {
                return new StandardDescendingMap();
            }
        }.descendingMap();
    }

    @Override
    public NavigableSet<K> navigableKeySet() {
        return new ForwardingNavigableMap<K, V>() {
            @Override
            protected NavigableMap<K, V> delegate() {
                return AbstractNavigableMap.this;
            }

            @Override
            public NavigableSet<K> navigableKeySet() {
                return new StandardNavigableKeySet();
            }
        }.navigableKeySet();
    }

    @Override
    public NavigableSet<K> descendingKeySet() {
        return descendingMap().navigableKeySet();
    }

    @Override
    public SortedMap<K, V> subMap(K fromKey, K toKey) {
        return subMap(fromKey, true, toKey, false);
    }

    @Override
    public NavigableMap<K, V> subMap(K fromKey, boolean fromInclusive, K toKey, boolean toInclusive) {
        return NavigableMapSubMap.subMapOf(this, fromKey, fromInclusive, toKey, toInclusive);
    }

    @Override
    public SortedMap<K, V> headMap(K toKey) {
        return headMap(toKey, false);
    }

    @Override
    public NavigableMap<K, V> headMap(K toKey, boolean inclusive) {
        return NavigableMapSubMap.headMapOf(this, toKey, inclusive);
    }

    @Override
    public SortedMap<K, V> tailMap(K fromKey) {
        return tailMap(fromKey, true);
    }

    @Override
    public NavigableMap<K, V> tailMap(K fromKey, boolean inclusive) {
        return NavigableMapSubMap.tailMapOf(this, fromKey, inclusive);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return new NavigableMapEntrySet<K, V>(this);
    }
}

/**
 * Provides a {@link NavigableMap} view of a key range of an underlying
 * {@link NavigableMap}.
 * 
 * @param <K> the type of keys maintained by this map
 * @param <V> the type of mapped values
 */
class NavigableMapSubMap<K, V> extends AbstractNavigableMap<K, V> {

    private static final int UNSPECIFIED = 0;
    private static final int INCLUSIVE = 1;
    private static final int EXCLUSIVE = 2;

    private final NavigableMap<K, V> base;
    private final Comparator<? super K> comparator;
    @NullableDecl
    private final K fromKey;
    private final int fromBound;
    @NullableDecl
    private final K toKey;
    private final int toBound;

    private NavigableMapSubMap(NavigableMap<K, V> base, K fromKey, int fromBound, K toKey,
            int toBound) {
        this.base = base;
        comparator = effectiveComparator(base.comparator());
        if (fromBound != UNSPECIFIED && toBound != UNSPECIFIED &&
                comparator.compare(fromKey, toKey) > 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("fromKey > toKey");
        }
        this.fromKey = fromKey;
        this.fromBound = fromBound;
        this.toKey = toKey;
        this.toBound = toBound;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    private static <K> Comparator<? super K> effectiveComparator(
            @NullableDecl Comparator<? super K> comparator) {
        return comparator != null ? comparator : (Comparator) Ordering.natural();
    }

    static <K, V> NavigableMap<K, V> subMapOf(NavigableMap<K, V> base, K fromKey,
            boolean fromInclusive, K toKey, boolean toInclusive) {
        return new NavigableMapSubMap<>(base, fromKey, fromInclusive ? INCLUSIVE : EXCLUSIVE,
                toKey, toInclusive ? INCLUSIVE : EXCLUSIVE);
    }

    static <K, V> NavigableMap<K, V> headMapOf(NavigableMap<K, V> base, K toKey, boolean inclusive) {
        return new NavigableMapSubMap<>(base, null, UNSPECIFIED, toKey, inclusive ? INCLUSIVE
                : EXCLUSIVE);
    }

    static <K, V> NavigableMap<K, V> tailMapOf(NavigableMap<K, V> base, K fromKey, boolean inclusive) {
        return new NavigableMapSubMap<>(base, fromKey, inclusive ? INCLUSIVE : EXCLUSIVE, null,
                UNSPECIFIED);
    }

    @Override
    public Comparator<? super K> comparator() {
        return base.comparator();
    }

    @NullableDecl
    private boolean aboveLowerBound(@NullableDecl K key, boolean inclusive) {
        if (fromBound != UNSPECIFIED) {
            final int cmp = comparator.compare(fromKey, key);
            if (fromBound == INCLUSIVE || !inclusive ? cmp > 0 : cmp >= 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @NullableDecl
    private boolean belowUpperBound(@NullableDecl K key, boolean inclusive) {
        if (toBound != UNSPECIFIED) {
            final int cmp = comparator.compare(key, toKey);
            if (toBound == INCLUSIVE || !inclusive ? cmp > 0 : cmp >= 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @NullableDecl
    private boolean inBounds(@NullableDecl K key, boolean inclusive) {
        return aboveLowerBound(key, inclusive) && belowUpperBound(key, inclusive);
    }

    @NullableDecl
    private Map.Entry<K, V> lowerBound(@NullableDecl Map.Entry<K, V> e) {
        if (e != null && fromBound != UNSPECIFIED) {
            final int cmp = comparator.compare(fromKey, e.getKey());
            if (fromBound == INCLUSIVE ? cmp > 0 : cmp >= 0) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return e;
    }

    @NullableDecl
    private Map.Entry<K, V> upperBound(@NullableDecl Map.Entry<K, V> e) {
        if (e != null && toBound != UNSPECIFIED) {
            final int cmp = comparator.compare(e.getKey(), toKey);
            if (toBound == INCLUSIVE ? cmp > 0 : cmp >= 0) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return e;
    }

    @NullableDecl
    private Map.Entry<K, V> bound(@NullableDecl Map.Entry<K, V> e) {
        return lowerBound(upperBound(e));
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return inBounds((K) key, true) && base.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public V get(Object key) {
        return inBounds((K) key, true) ? base.get(key) : null;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public V remove(Object key) {
        return inBounds((K) key, true) ? base.remove(key) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Map.Entry<K, V> lowerEntry(K key) {
        return bound(base.lowerEntry(key));
    }

    @Override
    public Map.Entry<K, V> floorEntry(K key) {
        return bound(base.floorEntry(key));
    }

    @Override
    public Map.Entry<K, V> ceilingEntry(K key) {
        return bound(base.floorEntry(key));
    }

    @Override
    public Map.Entry<K, V> higherEntry(K key) {
        return bound(base.higherEntry(key));
    }

    @Override
    public Map.Entry<K, V> firstEntry() {
        switch (fromBound) {
        case UNSPECIFIED:
            return base.firstEntry();
        case INCLUSIVE:
            return upperBound(base.floorEntry(fromKey));
        default:
            return upperBound(base.higherEntry(fromKey));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map.Entry<K, V> lastEntry() {
        switch (toBound) {
        case UNSPECIFIED:
            return base.firstEntry();
        case INCLUSIVE:
            return lowerBound(base.ceilingEntry(toKey));
        default:
            return lowerBound(base.lowerEntry(toKey));
        }
    }

    private NavigableMap<K, V> subMap(K fromKey, int fromBound, K toKey, int toBound) {
        if (fromBound == UNSPECIFIED) {
            fromKey = this.fromKey;
            fromBound = this.fromBound;
        } else if (!inBounds(fromKey, fromBound == INCLUSIVE)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("fromKey out of range");
        }
        if (toBound == UNSPECIFIED) {
            toKey = this.toKey;
            toBound = this.toBound;
        } else if (!inBounds(toKey, toBound == INCLUSIVE)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("toKey out of range");
        }
        return new NavigableMapSubMap<>(base, fromKey, fromBound, toKey, toBound);
    }

    @Override
    public NavigableMap<K, V> subMap(K fromKey, boolean fromInclusive, K toKey, boolean toInclusive) {
        return subMap(fromKey, fromInclusive ? INCLUSIVE : EXCLUSIVE, toKey,
                toInclusive ? INCLUSIVE : EXCLUSIVE);
    }

    @Override
    public NavigableMap<K, V> headMap(K toKey, boolean inclusive) {
        return subMap(null, UNSPECIFIED, toKey, inclusive ? INCLUSIVE : EXCLUSIVE);
    }

    @Override
    public NavigableMap<K, V> tailMap(K fromKey, boolean inclusive) {
        return subMap(fromKey, inclusive ? INCLUSIVE : EXCLUSIVE, null, UNSPECIFIED);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return new NavigableMapEntrySet<K, V>(this) {
            @Override
            protected Map.Entry<K, V> higherEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> from) {
                // omit unnecessary lower bound check of outer higherEntry
                return upperBound(base.higherEntry(from.getKey()));
            }
        };
    }
}

/**
 * Provides a {@link Map#entrySet()} implementation based on a
 * {@link NavigableMap} using the following methods:
 * 
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link NavigableMap#firstEntry()}</li>
 * <li>{@link NavigableMap#higherEntry(Object)}</li>
 * <li>{@link Map#get(Object)}</li>
 * <li>{@link Map#remove(Object)}</li>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * Note that {@link Collection#size()} is implemented in terms of iteration
 * using {@code firstEntry} and {@code higherEntry}, and therefore executes in
 * time proportional to the map size. Subclasses may wish to provide a more
 * efficient implementation.
 * 
 * @param <K> the type of keys maintained by this map
 * @param <V> the type of mapped values
 */
public class NavigableMapEntrySet<K, V> extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> {

    private final NavigableMap<K, V> map;

    /**
     * Constructs a {@link NavigableMapEntrySet} for the given map.
     * 
     * @param map the map whose entries are being represented
     */
    public NavigableMapEntrySet(NavigableMap<K, V> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    /**
     * Used by {@link #iterator()} to return an entry associated with the least
     * key in this map, or {@code null} if the map is empty. The default
     * implementation simply calls {@link NavigableMap#firstEntry()}; subclasses
     * may wish to provide a more efficient implementation.
     * 
     * @return an entry with the least key, or null if the map is empty
     */
    protected Map.Entry<K, V> firstEntry() {
        return map.firstEntry();
    }

    /**
     * Used by {@link #iterator()} to return an entry associated with the least
     * key strictly greater than the key of the given entry, or {@code null} if
     * there is no such key. The default implementation simply calls
     * {@link NavigableMap#higherEntry(Object)} with the key of the given entry;
     * subclasses may wish to provide a more efficient implementation.
     * 
     * @param from the reference entry, which must have been returned from this
     *            entry set
     * @return an entry with the least key greater than the given entry, or null
     *         if there is no such key
     */
    protected Map.Entry<K, V> higherEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> from) {
        return map.higherEntry(from.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
            @NullableDecl
            Map.Entry<K, V> prevEntry = null;
            @NullableDecl
            Map.Entry<K, V> nextEntry = firstEntry();

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return nextEntry != null;
            }

            @Override
            public Map.Entry<K, V> next() {
                if (!hasNext()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
                prevEntry = nextEntry;
                nextEntry = higherEntry(nextEntry);
                return prevEntry;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                if (prevEntry == null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException();
                }
                map.remove(prevEntry.getKey());
                prevEntry = null;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return Iterators.size(iterator());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Map.Entry) {
            final Map.Entry<?, ?> e = (Map.Entry<?, ?>) o;
            return Objects.equals(map.get(e.getKey()), e.getValue());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Map.Entry) {
            final Map.Entry<?, ?> e = (Map.Entry<?, ?>) o;
            final Object key = e.getKey();
            if (Objects.equals(map.get(key), e.getValue())) {
                map.remove(key);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- ForwardingNavigableMap

You must have a `NavigableMap` in advance if you use `ForwardingNavigableMap` which uses [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). So this is not what you need.

- AbstractMap

`AbstractMap` provides skeletal implementation of the `Map`. This class helps you implement a `Map` which is interface of `NavigableMap`, but without 'Navigable logic'. Anyway, `NavigableMap` is-a `Map`, so `AbstractMap` helps to setup a `NavigableMap`. Compared to `ForwardingNavigableMap`, I think `AbstractMap` can be your better choice.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest to consider something simpler as `NavigableMap` is a pretty rich interface and you may end up spending a lot of time on features you may not need. Even a plain `Map` has tons of methods and `AbstractMap` hardly helps as it provides only very rudimentary implementations (either inefficient or throwing `UnsupportedOperationException`).

If you could use `List` (with `sublist` for "navigation"), you'd save yourself a lot of work. Anyway, look at [guava-testlib](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-testlib) for a good testsuite.

If you really need a `NavigableMap`, I'm afraid, you're out of luck. I guess, there's no suitable base class as it's impossible to write something useful often enough.

> For instance, it seems like firstEntry of a sub/tail map could just call ceilingEntry(minKey) or higherEntry(minKey), depending on whether minKey is inclusive.

Yes, but this is a rather simple case. And there may be a faster way for `firstEntry` for a given implementation.